# Performing SoapUI API Calls with Python

Tags: python, api, server, python-requests, soapui

I am trying to call a POST API that would schedule a recording for a TV channel. The call works on SoapUI, but I can't seem to replicate the success in python (I can check whether it succeeds or not by checking my TV if a recording is scheduled). Here is the call in SoapUI: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwE0i.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pzC5.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfbPl.png)

Here is the call in Python (using pydev):

```
print("Record")  
url1 = "http://10.10.120.48:8080/api/CreateRecordSchedule"
{
    "type": "SERIES_PROGRAM",
    "matchingID": "SH00000000131221",
    "channelID": 11,
    "padIn": 0,
    "padOut": 0,
    "persistedRecordings": 5,
     "hd": False,
    "rerun": True
}
rsp = s.post(url1)

print (rsp.status_code)
```

Other api calls with the same server work fine, so I was wondering what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're including the data payload as part of your URL. Is that what you intended?

If you're just `POST`ing a JSON payload, the following should do the job:

```
import requests

url1 = 'http://10.10.120.48:8080/api/CreateRecordSchedule'
payload = '''{
    "type": "SERIES_PROGRAM",
    "matchingID": "SH00000000131221",
    "channelID": 11,
    "padIn": 0,
    "padOut": 0,
    "persistedRecordings": 5,
     "hd": False,
    "rerun": True
}'''
rsp = requests.post(url1, data=payload)
```